# how to use curl to post message to a facebook business page?

Tags: php, curl

I wonder there is a way to post a message to a facebook business page with cURL?

thanks

Comment: definitely a way, but what did you try to do so far ?

Comment: I can post message to my wall with cURL, but I can not post to my business. I got problem: with the same url address, the cURL code got different page with the browser.

Comment: I was able to post a status in my facebook page using cURL but it's hard to post a link with thumbnails and descriptions. :D

Answer (score 3):

here is roughly what you need without entirely doing it for you:

```
<?php
$poststring = "email=" . $email . "&pass=" . $password;
$ch = curl_init('http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$poststring");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

You want to build on the &poststring variable. This is what will actually contain the information you are going to send. For each field in the form, you must put that field name in the string, and then populate it with the data you want.

A good way to find all those easily is to open up the page in firefox with the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) and it will show you every field that's used in the form, and what name it is.

Beware, to prevent spam there are lot of tokens and authentication stuff put in hidden fields to prevent abuse (which hopefully isn't what you're doing) and you will have to figure out how to generate or obtain that information.

Comment: +1 the the web dev toolbar, but I prefer firebug.com but just my opinion

Comment: I think facebook might have an API to do that but never looked into it

Comment: Hi Jeremy, thanks for your answer, but that is not what i want to do.
I do not want to use cURL to create a new business page. I want to do is how to post a message to an existing business page.
the code you post can not do want you want

Comment: What he showed you is how to do a post. You can apply his code to other POST's as well.

Answer (score 2):

After you have authenticated the user and gotten a publish_right token run the script below

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/user_id/feed";
$ch = curl_init();
$attachment =  array(   'access_token'  => access_token_here,                        
                    'name'          => "Rave Kenya",
                    'link'          => "www.youtube.com",
                    'description'   => 'Testing a new facebook app',
                    'message' => 'Tested',

                );

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $attachment);
$result =curl_exec($ch);
```

curl_close ($ch);

Answer (score 1):

Although just using curl sounds simpler, the most reliable and forward-compatible option is likely implementing Facebook's API.  Using the API you can call [Stream.publish](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/) with your Page's ID as the target ID.

Comment: the problem of use facebook APT is I can not use API with out the facebook application